# PHP Access Denied

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile, mysqli

I'm trying to connect my databases to my online website and I keep getting these error for my code.

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045):
>   Access denied for user 'DatabaseName'@'28.5.2.24' (using password:
>   YES) in /home/user/public_html/getTemps.php on line 2

and the error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   /home/username/public_html/getTemps.php on line 3

Here is all of my code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "databasename", "password!",   "tablename");
    $result = $mysqli_query($con, "Selcect * From tablename");
    $data = fetch_all($result, MySQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

Comment: `$mysqli_query`? Also what is `fetch_all`? I'm not sure what the last parameter is in your `mysqli_connect` if it the database name I'm wondering why it's called **tablename**.

Comment: To start with there is a typo on the word "Select"

Comment: Its an SQL query from php and the other line grabs the results and give them back in a certain format

Comment: The last parameter is the name of the table that's in the database

Comment: Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php You need to provide right parameters in right order.

Answer (score 1):

Not a recommended way to connect to your database as it looks messy. Please change your 'Selcect' before starting it. Please read the documentation as there is no such function called 'fetch_all'. There is one but called 'mysqli_fetch_all'.

What I recommend you to use is this

```
$HOST = '';
$USERNAME = '';
$PASSWORD = '';
$DB = '';  //Your database name
$link = mysqli_connect($HOST, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DB);

if (!$link) {

//your error message

}

//Start of your query
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "databasename", "password!",   "tablename");
$result = $mysqli_query($con, "Selcect * From tablename");
$data = fetch_all($result, MySQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

Change the above to this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password!","databasename");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = fetch_all($result, MySQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

if you want to connect like this, which I do not recommend define: host, username, password(if set) and the database name. The tablename is optional but see as you define that in the query it is not necessary to define that in the connection string.(I do indeed recommend to you do as eddie sayed and put all of the connection string information into variables. As it is easier to work with.)

as for the query ofcourse the typo "Selcect" needs to be `SELECT`.